# uri change in niceditor

Tags: tomcat, nicedit

I am using niceditor plugins in my web applications. Now, the problem is plugin is uploading the image to this default location [http://i.imgur.com/][1]. But I want to store these images to my desired location on our server. I read this post http://eaktadiur.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/change-nicedit-upload-file-path/, but I am not able to understand where to put nic_uploaded.php file. I tried to put this under my root directory of tomcat server, but it is not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is that you download/open up [fillder2](http://www.fiddler2.com), this will allow you to see exactly what URI nicEdit is trying to query when you action an upload.

If it is still going to imgur.com, then you need to ensure that in your nicEdit.js that the `nicURI` property of `nicUploadButton` has been updated from `'http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json'`.

If the upload is successfully finding your nic_upload.php file, then you must ensure that your definitions are correct for `'NICUPLOAD_PATH'` and `'NICUPLOAD_URI'` and that the relevant folders exist. If this doesn't resolve the issue, check fiddler for an error message (using web view), which might lead to a resolution.

Hope this helps!